# Use of "this reviewer" in a review

Tags: peer-review

I sent a article for reviewing before publication.

In the review I received, I had the following comment:

> From very similar studies this reviewer knows well that [...]

This is the first sentence of a bullet list, with each item being largely independent of each other.
There was no mention of a reviewer earlier in the review.

I have two questions:

- It seems to me that "this reviewer" refers to... the reviewer her/himself.  Am I correct?  Of note, the reviewer may not be a native speaker.
- Is it widely used?  Especially compared to using "I" (just like other reviewers do)?

Comment: Not really a question about Academia

Comment: For your second question, see: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/154165/19607

Comment: This might be more suited for one of the English language sites.

Comment: It reminds me of military boot camp where the construct "This recruit" is preferred over "I".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It refers to the reviewer writing the review. It's not that widely used (and personally I don't like it), but I have seen it in reviews, and as a native speaker I don't find it that unusual. It allows the reviewer to respond in the academic third person (a bit like saying "the authors" in a paper) - a grammatical construct to allow them to write with an academic tone.

Personally I just say "I think"!

Comment: "We" is not third person -- it is first person plural.

Comment: It is possibly an overreaction to the often made assertion that a person should limit the amount of times they refer to themselves when discussing something to avoid seeming self important.  It's certainly possible a non-native English speaker could consider this to be more strict of a rule than it actually is but I think anyone can fall in to a habit like that.  In my case I was told not to start a sentence with "and" or "but" when I was in school and even though I've read it's acceptable I still jump through hoops to avoid it in my writing.

Comment: @nanomam well, if we can be singular as a pluralis majestatis, why can we not be third person in whatever is the opposite of pluralis majestatis?

Comment: @nanoman you're right, edited

Comment: When I see or have used something like “this reviewer”, it’s often been a deliberate attempt to take emotion out of a contentious (or potentially contentious) disagreement between the reviewer and the authors.